# OLS Graph interpretation

Tags: data-visualization, least-squares, interpretation

In a graph containing the data points of different industries, there is an OLS line passing through it. If I now want to interpret the OLS line and an industry's position relative to the OLS line, how could I say it in words?

X- Axis: Profits
Y-Axis: Innovation

Comment: What are the labels on the axes of the graph?

Comment: @BruceET X-axis - Profits, Y-Axis - Innovation

Comment: If the line has positive slope, then innovation increases with profits. You can't automatically interpret this as cause-and-effect, but you might be able to use it for prediction, especially if points lie near the line: If a company from this population has high profits then its level of innovation may be also be high--similar to other companies with similarly high profits.

Comment: @BruceET But with an OLS line, can we mention something about the mean as well?

Comment: For OLS with usual assumptions, the mean Innovation of all companies with a given profit number is the height of the line directly above the profit number.

Comment: Then for a data point above that line, can we say that the innovation for that particular industry is greater than the mean?

Answer (score 0):

The graph reflects the heterogeneity across industries of their *Innovations* with respect to their *Profits*. I assume that the graph is computed that every point representing a Industry contains the mean *Profits* and *Innovations* of the Industry. Then we could observe which industries deviate the greatest from the trend line.